# jQuery .val() not getting value from one input, fine on the rest

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor

I need to validate  a number of fields in my ASP MVC3 view and am trying to use jQuery to do so. The jQuery `.val()` method pulls the `accountNumber`, `refNumber`, and `ownerMaster` from the input fields just fine, however the `agentId` field always has a value of `""` regardless of anything.

I've looked over and over for a typo in my code and haven't found it. Hoping another set of eyes does the trick.

FYI - if I change the `.val()` on `$('#AgentId').val()` below to `.hide()` the hide method works and the field disappears, which means I have the selector typed correctly.

**jQuery**

```
function ValidateFields(transactionType) {
    var msg = "";
    var refNumber = $('#RefNumber').val();
    var ownerMaster = $('#OwnerMasterAgentId').val();
    var accountNumber = $('#AccountNumber').val();
    var agentId = $('#AgentId').val(); //When the agentId variable an selector + val() are
                                       //evaluated here both have a value of ""
```

**ASP MVC Razor**

```
                <div class="M-editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RefNumber)
                    <span class="alwaysReq"> @Html.Raw("*")</span>
                </div>
                <div class="M-editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RefNumber, new { maxlength = 9, @class = "staticData" })
                </div>
                <div class="M-editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OwnerMasterAgentId)
                    <span class="req">@Html.Raw("*")</span> 
                </div>
                <div class="M-editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OwnerMasterAgentId, new { maxlength = 8, @class="staticData" })
                </div>
                    <div class="M-editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountNumber)
                        <span class="req">@Html.Raw("*")</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="M-editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AccountNumber, new { maxlength = 17 })
                    </div>
                    <div class="M-editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AgentId)
                        <span class="req">@Html.Raw("*")</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="M-editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AgentId, new { maxlength = 8 })
                    </div>
```

**HTML**

```
                <div class="M-editor-label">
                    <label for="RefNumber">Reference Number</label>
                    <span class="alwaysReq" style="display: inline;"> *</span>
                </div>
                <div class="M-editor-field">
                    <input class="staticData" id="RefNumber" maxlength="9" name="RefNumber" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="M-editor-label">
                    <label for="OwnerMasterAgentId">Owner Master Agent Id</label>
                    <span class="req" style="display: inline;">*</span> 
                </div>
                <div class="M-editor-field">
                    <input class="staticData" id="OwnerMasterAgentId" maxlength="8" name="OwnerMasterAgentId" type="text" value="">
                </div
                    <div class="M-editor-label">
                        <label for="AccountNumber">Account Number</label>
                        <span class="req" style="display: inline;">*</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="M-editor-field">
                        <input id="AccountNumber" maxlength="17" name="AccountNumber" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="M-validator-field">
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="AccountNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true" style="display: none;"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="M-editor-label">
                        <label for="AgentId">Agent ID</label>
                        <span class="req" style="display: inline;">*</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="M-editor-field">
                        <input id="AgentId" maxlength="8" name="AgentId" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
```

Comment: When/how do you call the `ValidateFields` function? Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: when you type the selector `$('#AgentId')` on console, the console return the input?

Comment: First debugging step, use console to do `$('#AgentId').length` to see if you're accidentally using the ID more than once on the page.

Comment: Setting it up on jsfiddle, it does work. It is probably related to how you call ValidateFields or the element exists more than once on the page: http://jsfiddle.net/BrCM3/

Comment: @ErikNoren ID selector only selects the first matching element, in this case `$('[id=AgentID]').length` will work.

Comment: @undefined Good point - I usually use this on class selectors to ensure I'm getting the right one and didn't think when I re-applied to id selecting. Not sure if I should edit or ...?

Answer (score 0):

i don't see the problem to,

1. but do you have any another html element have id=AgentId in ur page
2. when you change the text of the field does it change in the firebug

actually you don't have to create ur own validation you can use data annotation validation 
which provides poth server side and client side validation

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var agentId=$('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.AgentId)').val();
```